# IOS - PickerView's keeping already open keyboard. LastResponder not working

Tags: ios

I am having trouble with a pickerview attached to a textview, I have a View with 3 text views, one that brings up a pickerview and two that take plain text. For all of them I stop the keyboard from popping up before editing begins however my problem is when I go from one of the TextViews to the TextView that opens the PickerView. I end up with the PickerView coming up and the prior keyboard staying. I have tried everything related to the lastresponder and I just cannot get that keyboard gone. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly call "`resignFirstResponder`" on all three text views when the picker appears.

And once the picker disappears, you can select the text view that brought up the picker and the keyboard will come back.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have no idea why I didnt try it there !

Comment: The code for show hide was on textFieldShouldBeginEditing and I checked the textfield, if it was the one I wanted I changed the pickerView's hidden attribute and returned NO, else I hid the pickerview and returned YES. Hope that helps someone